# How to get the proper SQL result from a query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view in my database that uses several tables and everything works fine the way it is now. I want to add another column/value based on whether a specific match is found in another table. I have used similar iterations in others, but this time I get a NULL result, even though there is a match.

Basically:

Table_2

| ID | Value | Text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Miss | Some text |
| 1 | Miss | Other text |
| 2 | Hit | OK |
| 2 | Miss | Always |
| 3 | Hit | Whatelse |

There is a correlation to another table that holds a value, equal to the ID in Table_2.

I want to use a case when and set a text based on this;

```
select 
    somefield1,
    somefield2,
    somefield3,
    case
        when 2.ID is not null then 'Real'
        else 'Fake'
    end somefield4
from
    table_1 1 (nolock)
left join 
    (select top (1) ID from table_2 where Value = 'Hit') 2 on 1.ID = 2.ID
```

If I run this script :

```
select top (1) ID 
from table_2 
where Value = 'Hit' and ID = 2
```

it returns: 2

If I run this :

```
select top (1) ID 
from table_2 
where Value = 'Hit' and ID = 1
```

it returns: NULL

But when I run the view, I get 'Fake' every single time, even though there is a match and the query returns a value.

Comment: Show sample data from *both* tables.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). If you must and you accept the errors and incorrect values, then AT LEAST use the current, non-deprecated syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `exists` to check if the appropriate row exists in the other table.  This looks like:

```
select t2.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from table_1 t1
                          where t1.id = t2.id and t1.event = 'Hit'
                         )
             then 'real' else 'fake'
        end)
from table_2 t2;
```

For performance, you want an index on `table_1(id, event)`.

Comment: THANK YOU! That gave me the result I wanted.
It did slow the query by a few seconds, but that's something I willing to live with, for now :)